# Center a text with his parent

Tags: css, text, alignment, parent

I'm not very good at CSS, I guess that will we easy to one of you.

Look at image below, i'm trying to center my text but center it with the div parent's width, as if there was no button, but I don't know how to proceed.

```
<div class="parent" style="width:500px;">
    <div class="container" style="width:400px;"> My text here </div>
    <button style="width:100px;">My Button</button>
</div>
```

I tried :

```
.parent { text-align: center; }
```

but that center the text with the .container width (so at 200px) but i'm looking for a way to center it a 250px here (.parent width)

I think about doing that with a padding-left but that's not a "clean" method in my case because button is not always displayed.

If someone knows how can I do that please :)

image:

[image]

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. :-) [After doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @Alex new users can not embed images.

Comment: Do you always know the width of the button? (i.e. is it one button with a fixed amount of text?)

Comment: Yes @ClaraB but sometimes the button isn't needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use absolute positioning on the button!

```css
.parent {
  position: relative; // position the button within the parent div
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0; // or whatever, position it where you want it
}


.container {
  padding-right: 100px; // so the text doesn't overlap with the button
  padding-left: 100px; // so the text is balanced 

  text-align: center;
}
```

EDIT:

And when the button isn't needed, you could use a conditional on the parent --

```css
.container--with-button {
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
.container--without-button {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, it works well thanks you !

Comment: @FlorianDA Glad to hear it! You can also mark this answer as "correct" to help other people with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right then all you'll need to do is add a text-align property to your div.

```
.div { text-align: center }
```

I made a quick example that matches your diagram here, hope it helps.
https://jsbin.com/qubeqezama/7/edit?html,css

Comment: If you want the content within the container to follow the parents style as well, ex: p, h1, h2... then you will need to have `text-align: inherit`

Comment: I edited my question, I already tried that @bstory but that center the text with the container width and not parent

Comment: that's what I want @SazzadHossain,I tried what you said but not working

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you only need to add `display: block;` to the `.parent` element. That way they'll be both displayed as a block and then all the text will be centered. ;)